# C# "is" operator

Tags: c#

I've found such code in my project (T is some UI class):

```
if (current.GetType() == typeof(T) || current.GetType().GetTypeInfo().IsSubclassOf(typeof(T)))
```

I think it can be replaced with
`current is T` or `typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(current))`.

Am I right?

Comment: Yes, I'd expect so. I can't immediately see any reason that wouldn't work. If you try it, do all your tests still pass?

Comment: It should be. I can't find counterexamples from top of my head.

Comment: Definitely `typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(current)).` will have different meaning (i.e. if `current` is `Object` at compile time.

Comment: I wouldn't actually expect `typeof(current)` to compile... I'd misread that as `current.GetType()`.

Comment: Actually, there is one difference in behavior: the existing code will throw an exception if `current` is null, but `current is T` won't.

Comment: Yeah, that worked as expected.